# Buying Steam game while being abroad

Tags: steam

I want to buy (pre-order) No Man's Sky from Steam. Since I'm from the Netherlands, this would normally cost me €60.

At the moment I'm on holiday in the United Kingdom. The game has a price here of £40. Because of the current exchange rate between euro and pound, this is a lot cheaper: 21%.

My question is: can I buy a Steam gift card in the United Kingdom and use it to buy the game from my own Steam account for the price it costs in the UK? If so, is this legal / do I have any risk of my account being blocked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

> Can I buy a Steam Card in the UK and use it on my account?

You can't.

[You used to be able to do it](https://web.archive.org/web/20180728193820/https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1122-RTSC-0478), [but due to fraud and currency exchange reasons](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1122-RTSC-0478), gift cards, like Apple/Google Play, are also region locked.

Instead, you are now encouraged to buy [Digital Giftcards](https://store.steampowered.com/digitalgiftcards/), which automatically convert currencies.

> Can I buy [Insert Game Name] at a cheaper price; more specifically, the UK's prices since I'm there?

Yes, only if you switch your store location. To do this, simply go to your [accounts page](https://store.steampowered.com/account) and select "[Update your store country](http://store.steampowered.com/account/change_country/)".
Only do this while you're in the UK.

This unfortunately means that any remaining wallet credit will be converted from euros to pounds, and some of its actual value may be lost due to conversion rates*. But on the plus side, the incoming money from your UK card will be 1:1 because it's the same currency.

*For example, if the rate is GBP:USD=X was 1.5, the effective rate that Steam will change Pounds into US Dollars will have a tax, so instead of getting $1.50 USD per pound, you'll only get $1.45 USD per pound. This value differs per currency and from minute-to-minute^.

You'll also require a local method of payment (ie. PayPal, Credit/Debit Card attached to a bank from that country).

^I seriously doubt that Steam will change its rates from minute-to-minute. AFAIK, it's more like daily.

> Is this legal, and will I risk getting my account blocked?

Yes, it is legal. However, to stick with the Steam Subscriber Agreement, I'd recommend switching back to your home country's store after returning home from the UK, **and to not use your Netherlands payment method (ie. credit cards)** as it is against the SSA to purchase from a store that you're not in. (ie. US store from Australia, despite both using the same currency, and oddly enough - In Australia, [we can choose to switch between US and AU stores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2RMG.png))

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

> **Are there country restrictions on Steam Wallet codes?**
>
> Steam Wallet codes typically do not have any country restrictions and can be redeemed worldwide (Note, some cards issued in Southeast Asia may only be redeemable in this region).
>
> **Can I redeem a Steam Wallet code that is in a different currency?**
>
> Yes, however you will be prompted to convert the value of the Steam Wallet code to the currency of your Steam Wallet as shown below. The daily currency conversion rate will be applied. 
>   [image: Currency Conversion]

Source: [Steam Wallet](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1122-RTSC-0478)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's nice to know that you can use Steam cards from every country. However, I don't want to change the currency. :) I want to buy a Steam gift card with a value in pounds and use it to buy a game in pounds. Just like someone from the United Kingdom would do, but now with my (initially) Dutch account where I've bought games in euros before.